# Eclipse doesn't show the dialog on build error

Tags: java, eclipse

Usually when your code has build errors eclipse asks you if you want to run your old code. Somebody pressed yes and don't ask again. Resulting in me not being able to see any build errors because the console resets after the build.

What I need is a way to reset this setting so this dialog shows again, so I can see whats wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset this setting in the Eclipse preferences under *Run/Debug-Launching*:

[image]